# PHP - Don't repeat random selection

Tags: php

I have a small PHP script that is selecting a random sentence from an array

```
$prefixes = array('sentence 1', 'sentence 2');

echo $prefixes[rand(0,count($prefixes)-1)];
```

How can I make it not pick the same sentence twice in a row?

Edit: Sorry, yeah there will be around 100 sentences and they can be used over and over again just not twice in a row. It's an on click event that re-loads the sentence to the page with AJAX and if it picks the same sentence twice in a row it looks like clicking the button hasn't done anything as there is no page refresh. Thanks

Edit 2: Basically it's a DIV with a sentence in, when you click a button it loads a new sentence into the DIV via AJAX and replaces the old sentence with the new one. Sometimes it was loading the same sentence twice in a row which gave the effect the button wasn't doing anything

Comment: Can a sentence be used again if its not consecutive?

Comment: I take it you have more than 2 sentences in the array, because at the moment the only solution is: `1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0`

Comment: minor point but if you determine what can and cannot be picked it won't be random will it?

Comment: Ha ha, yeah but see my above edit, there is a specific reason, it doesn't have to be truly random anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();
$prev = isset($_SESSION['last_number']) ? $_SESSION['last_number'] : null;
do {
  $_SESSION['last_number'] = mt_rand(0,count($prefixes)-1);
} while ($_SESSION['last_number'] === $prev);
echo $prefixes[$_SESSION['last_number']];
```

Of course, make sure you have more than one element in `$prefixes`, or else it will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Well, what you could do is use [`shuffle`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) instead:

```
$prefixes = array('sentence 1', 'sentence 2');
shuffle($prefixes);
```

Then, either remove them after each use:

```
$prefix = array_pop($prefixes); // Removes the element when it returns
```

Or increment the array:

```
$prefix = current($prefixes); // fetches the current element
next($prefixes); //increments the internal array pointer
```

Comment: id rather use array_pop for better performance. according to this link http://kb.ucla.edu/articles/performance-of-array_shift-and-array_pop-in-php array_pop ist at least 1000 times faster.

Comment: Fair point.  You can use pop instead (since it's semantically the same since order doesn't matter)...

Comment: Does removing them remove them for good or just until the shuffle starts again?

Comment: What do you mean?  What exactly are you trying to do?  If I understand you (which I don't), try just replacing the `echo` line with `echo array_pop($prefixes);`...  Or with `echo current($prefixes); next($prefixes);` depending on what you want to do...

Comment: This answer doesn't actually address the question. (See his edit.) He's using AJAX to load a single sentence per page load.

Comment: Sorry my edit came up after he had answered, he was answering an older question, using the echo array_pop($prefixes); seems to have worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Dan, if you are loading the page multiple times with AJAX as your edit suggests, you need to remember the prior state. Else this ends up being just another way to pick a random element from the array.

Comment: Ah OK so is shuffle not enough? Basically it's a DIV with a sentence in, when you click a button it loads a new sentence into the DIV via AJAX and replaces the old sentence with the new one. Sometimes it was loading the same sentence twice in a row which gave the effect the button wasn't doing anything.

Comment: It still selects some of them twice in a row

Comment: @Dan, ircmaxell's code is an excellent way to consecutively iterate through an array in a random fashion without repeating any elements. However, every time you call that page via AJAX it starts over again and can easily choose the same element. So you must store which element was last used for the user. Sessions are designed to solve that problem. (See my answer for a simple implementation.)

Comment: Ahh OK that makes sense now, thank you for the explanation, I've just used it and it works! Cool.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a new function. Record the previous result of `rand()`, and check the current result against it. While these two values are the same, call `rand()` again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't get what you want to do, but I'll try: You want to choose a number of sentences from an array of sentences randomly and unique?

```
// version 1: shuffle!
shuffle($sentences);
$result = array_slice($sentences, 0, NUMBER_OF_SENTENCES);

// version 2: array_rand!
// a) $result will contain the INDEX in the entry in the $sentences array.
$result = array_rand($sentences, NUMBER_OF_SENTENCES);
// b) $result will contain the sentences
$result = array_rand(array_flip($sentences), NUMBER_OF_SENTENCES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're loading this via Ajax, you'll just have to pass the sentence index number around with the Ajax calls to prevent the same sentence twice in a row. When you return a sentence, return the sentence itself and its index. When you request a new sentence, pass the old sentence index. Don't shuffle the array itself, so you can identify the same sentence between requests.